Benchmarking with moveit_ros_benchmarks: Cannot find configuration files
I want to benchmark OMPL planners in MoveIt (ROS 2 Humble, Ubuntu 22.04).
My code/workspace: https://github.com/wallelikesjinglebells/ws_pcl
Here's what I'm doing:

My starting point is a PLY file, and I am successfully reading and publishing the file as a PointCloud2 message (package: pcl_publisher).
Used command: ros2 run pcl_publisher pcl_publisher_node ~/ws_pcl/src/pcl_publisher/resource/TrialWall_KUKA_PC.ply
I am taking the PointCloud2 message and remapping octomap_server_node's subscription to /pcl, my point cloud topic.
Used command: ros2 run octomap_server octomap_server_node --ros-args -p frame_id:=world -r /cloud_in:=/pcl
I am taking the data from octomap_server_node and publishing it to the planning scene (package: octomap_publisher).
Used command: ros2 run octomap_publisher octomap_publisher_node
I am using a KUKA robot. Used command: ros2 launch kuka_moveit_config demo.launch.py
I want to benchmark OMPL planners on my scenario. I have written a ompl_benchmark.yaml file for this purpose. Used command: ros2 run moveit_ros_benchmarks moveit_run_benchmark --config ~/ws_pcl/src/kuka_moveit_config/config/ompl_benchmark.yaml

When I run the last command, however, I get these messages:
[WARN] [1728468684.413445593] [moveit.ros.benchmarks.BenchmarkOptions]: No benchmark_config found on param server
[INFO] [1728468684.472271772] [moveit_rdf_loader.rdf_loader]: Loaded robot model in 0.0566256 seconds
[INFO] [1728468684.472475344] [moveit_robot_model.robot_model]: Loading robot model 'kuka_kr210_arm'...
[WARN] [1728468684.498408077] [moveit_ros.robot_model_loader]: No kinematics plugins defined. Fill and load kinematics.yaml!
[ERROR] [1728468684.556276211] [moveit.ros.benchmarks.BenchmarkExecutor]: No planning pipelines have been loaded. Nothing to do for the benchmarking service.
[ERROR] [1728468684.556326918] [moveit.ros.benchmarks.BenchmarkExecutor]: No planning pipelines configured.  Did you call BenchmarkExecutor::initialize?
[ERROR] [1728468684.556340178] [moveit.ros.benchmarks.RunBenchmark]: Failed to run all benchmarks

This is the content of my ompl_benchmark.yaml file:
benchmark_config:
  # Name of the benchmark session
  benchmark_name: "OMPL_Benchmark_KUKA"

  # Number of times to run each planner
  runs: 10

  # Timeout for each planning query (in seconds)
  timeout: 10.0

  # Set to false to avoid displaying the scene during the benchmarking process
  display_scene: false

  # OMPL planners to benchmark
  planners:
    - plugin: ompl_interface/OMPLPlanner
      planner_ids:
        - RRTConnectkConfigDefault
        - RRTstarkConfigDefault
        - PRMkConfigDefault

  # Planning pipeline (using OMPL)
  planning_pipeline: "ompl"

  # Paths to the robot's URDF and SRDF descriptions
  robot_description: "robot_description"
  robot_description_semantic: "robot_description_semantic"

  # Planning group
  group_name: "kuka_arm"

  # Octomap topic from octomap_server
  octomap_topic: "/octomap_binary"

  # Start state
  start_state:
    joint_state:
      joint_names:
        - joint_1
        - joint_2
        - joint_3
        - joint_4
        - joint_5
        - joint_6
      joint_values:
        - 25.0
        - 40.0
        - 5.0
        - 0.0
        - 0.0
        - 0.0

  # Goal state
  goal_state:
    joint_state:
      joint_names:
        - joint_1
        - joint_2
        - joint_3
        - joint_4
        - joint_5
        - joint_6
      joint_values:
        - -25.0
        - 40.0
        - 5.0
        - 0.0
        - 0.0
        - 0.0

It seems that the robot model is being loaded, but then it requires kinematics plugins and planning pipelines.
I do have a kinematics.yaml file under kuka_moveit_config/config with this content:
kuka_arm:
  kinematics_solver: kdl_kinematics_plugin/KDLKinematicsPlugin
  kinematics_solver_search_resolution: 0.0050000000000000001
  kinematics_solver_timeout: 0.0050000000000000001

The planning pipelines are defined in my ompl_benchmark.yaml file, but why does moveit_run_benchmark not find the planning pipelines?
I'd be very grateful if someone could help me out!
Note:
I am aware of this tutorial, but when trying to adapt it for my purpose (see run_kuka_benchmarks.launch.py in kuka_moveit_config/launch, running with ros2 launch kuka_moveit_config run_kuka_benchmarks.launch.py), I get an error I find even more difficult to resolve:
[ERROR] [launch]: Caught exception in launch (see debug for traceback): Caught multiple exceptions when trying to load file of format [py]:
 - PackageNotFoundError: "package 'kuka_moveit_config_moveit_config' not found, searching: [...]"
 - InvalidFrontendLaunchFileError: The launch file may have a syntax error, or its format is unknown

Nowhere in my code have I found a mention of the package kuka_moveit_config_moveit_config and I don't understand why the launch searches for that package. So I'm sticking to trying to troubleshoot my first approach for now. If someone does know how to resolve this though, I'd be happy to know as well.
